# Should I import a model only to use type hint in Python?

Tags: python, django, type-hinting

I have noticed that in many cases I am trying to use type hints in a file that doesn't have this class imported. I wonder whether using type hints is reasonable in such scenario (which means that I will have to import the class)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to use a particular class in type hints it means you anyway have a dependency on this class, so importing it should not be a bad idea. You may encounter a problem of cyclic dependencies however if your code is not properly structured. To overcome that, you can import dependencies only while type checking:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from XX import YY
```